# How to to strip simple quotes from bash script

Tags: bash, docker, shell, github-actions

I am trying to run maven through a docker image using a shell script

When running docker in the shell, I use `sed` to remove single quotes:

bash script:

```
docker run $(echo "-e CUCUMBER_FILTER_TAGS=$CUCUMBER_FILTER_TAGS $RUN_ARGUMENT $INPUT_MAVEN_COMMAND $MAVEN_ARGUMENTS $AUTHENTICATION" | sed "s/'//g")
```

is translated into

```
docker run -e 'CUCUMBER_FILTER_TAGS="@bidrag-person' and not '@ignored"' --rm -v /home/deployer/actions-bidrag-cucumber-backend/ws/bidrag-cucumber-backend/bidrag-cucumber-backend:/usr/src/mymaven -v /home/deployer/.m2:/root/.m2 -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:3.6.3-openjdk-15 mvn test -e -DUSERNAME=j104364 -DINTEGRATION_INPUT=json/integrationInput.json -DUSER_AUTH=*** -DTEST_AUTH=*** -DPIP_AUTH=***
```

how can I remove those extra single quotes around and within CUCUMBER_FILTER_TAGS that seems to pop up from nowhere?

I cannot solve this and are seeking a solution. This script (https://github.com/navikt/bidrag-maven/blob/feature/filter.tags/cucumber-backend/cucumber.sh) is being run from a cron job on GitHub (GitHub Actions, part of a GitHub workflow)

The other variables (which are not inputs to this script) are set as environment variables from GitHub secrets in a GitHub workflow

```
AUTHENTICATION="-DUSER_AUTH=$USER_AUTHENTICATION -DTEST_AUTH=$TEST_USER_AUTHENTICATION -DPIP_AUTH=$PIP_USER_AUTHENTICATION"
```

are set in in a GitHub workflow yaml file like this:

```yaml
      - uses: navikt/bidrag-maven/cucumber-backend@v6
        with:
          maven_image: maven:3.6.3-openjdk-15
          username: j104364
        env:
          USER_AUTHENTICATION: ${{ secrets.USER_AUTHENTICATION }}
          TEST_USER_AUTHENTICATION: ${{ secrets.TEST_USER_AUTHENTICATION }}
          PIP_USER_AUTHENTICATION: ${{ secrets.PIP_USER_AUTHENTICATION }}
```

Comment: Neither the command substitution itself nor the `echo` command within introduces literal single quotes.  They are coming from something else, after the fact, presumably reflecting the *logical* result of expanding the overall `docker` command.

Comment: Is it `set -x` output you're comparing against and seeing single quotes in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while these answers work to some degree, they will not function in my use case... I have recently upgraded the server where these scripts are used, and I have moved on to other scripting languages...

Conclusion:
Bash scripting is hard and painstaking... Both of these suggestions are functioning (sort of), but not as intended...

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an array.

```
docker_options=( 
  -e "CUCUMBER_FILTER_TAGS=$CUCUMBER_FILTER_TAGS"
  "$RUN_ARGUMENT"
  "$INPUT_MAVEN_COMMAND"
  "$MAVEN_ARGUMENTS"
  "$AUTHENTICATION"
)

docker run "${docker_options[@]}"
```

Comment: this seems to be a nice solution, but it only creates more quotes: docker run -e 'CUCUMBER_FILTER_TAGS="@bidrag-person and not @ignored"' '--rm -v /home/J104364/ws/bidrag-cucumber-backend:/usr/src/mymaven -v /home/J104364/.m2:/root/.m2 -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:3.6.3-openjdk-15 mvn' test '-e -DUSERNAME=j104364 -DINTEGRATION_INPUT=json/integrationInput.json ' '-DUSER_AUTH=*** -DTEST_AUTH=*** -DPIP_AUTH=***'

Comment: You probably should not include the quotes in the first place, as they were only added in an attempt to store values in a regular variable.

Comment: I cannot solve this... if any would like to have a try: https://github.com/navikt/bidrag-maven/blob/feature/filter.tags/cucumber-backend/cucumber.sh

Comment: Update your question with how you set the other variables as well.